# SQL Sum Row number until condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so in my database i have two rows: Barcode, Profit ;
They are in an descending order according to profit, eg:

```
Barcode , Profit:
101 , 10000
106 , 9999
107 , 8888
108 , 222
```

i need to sql query which will do the following:
I need to sum all the profit then look at its %80 value and then start summing barcode values until %80 is met, eg:

```
Barcode , Profit:
101 , 10000
106 , 9999
107 , 8888
108 , 222
```

10000+9999+8888+222= 29109

29109 is the total sum and its %80 is = 23 287,2

since 10000+9999+8888 does contain the %80the result should return:

```
Barcode
101
106
107
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@sump := @sump + profit) as running_profit
      from t cross join
           (select @sump := 0) params
      order by profit desc
     ) t
where running_profit < 0.8 * @sump;
```

The inner query calculates the cumulative profit.  As a side effect, it also calculates the total sum of the profit.

The outer `where` select all rows up to the first row that exceeds the 80% threshold.